# Adding SVG icons results in my iOS app increasing app size by 30MB

Tags: ios, xcode, svg

In my iOS app I added 260 SVG icons. This resulted in the app size increasing by 30MB.
To solve this problem, I had to use PNGs instead.

Can anyone please help to get the answer?

Comment: What is your deployment target set to?

Comment: And what is the original total size of those 260 icons?

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/FileManagement/Conceptual/On_Demand_Resources_Guide/index.html

Comment: @Andrew iOS13.0

Comment: @bjorn.lau it’s 3MB

Comment: @Andrew  iOS13.0

Answer (score 2):

After compiling the .xcassets file in your project, you will get the asset catalog file (.car). You can see that each svg in the `.car` file will generate three other images with different scales (@1x, @2x, @3x), so when using vector resources (svg/pdf) you will get four files in total, which may increase the size of your App.

To analyze `.car` files you can use the command line
`assetutil -I Assets.car`, which will print the contents of the json file in the `.car` file.

Also you can use [AssetCatalogTinkerer](https://github.com/insidegui/AssetCatalogTinkerer) to open asset catalog files (.car) and view the images that they contain.

In order to compile xcassets manually, you can use `actool`. For your reference the usage looks like:

`xcrun actool Assets.xcassets --compile build --platform iphoneos --minimum-deployment-target 15.0`.